# What preposition is appropriate?

Tags: prepositions

There is 80% chance of rain.

I want to covert this statement into this:

> It will rain **(preposition)** 80% chance.

What preposition is appropriate in the parentheses between “rains” and “80%”?

Comment: I wouldn't convert the statement that way, and I'm not sure you can.

Comment: A possible candidate is **with a(n)**, as in "It will rain with an 80% chance," which I suppose gets your point across. But I don't think it's grammatically correct, and certainly not idiomatic.

Comment: Note that it should be "an 80% chance". In formal writing, it is more conventional to say "with a probability of 80%".

Comment: I also came here to give randomhead's possible answer "with a/an", so I'll just add that it doesn't make sense because "It will rain" means 100%, but then you say 80%. If you edit your question to include what context you want to use this expression about percent, it will make it easier for us to give a good and confident answer